# How to eliminate the empty rows from the jTable jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jtable, jquery-jtable

I have two jTables in my web page, which loads data from a database. The first jTable fetches the data directly from the database and the second table loads its data according to the selected data in the first table.

The problem now I am facing is, in-case if there are no data to be fetched for the second table, from the particular selected row, the rows are displaying empty.

For example, I have selected a data in the table 1, but since there is no data related to the selected data, the second table is displaying empty rows.

[image: This is the second table which displays empty rows.]

How to hide or not to fetch if the rows were completely empty at the same time if the row has even a single entry I wanted to display that row.

I am using python in the back end to fetch the data. So, do I need to make changes in my python code or do I need to make a change in the front end jQuery or CSS.

I have tried to use the jQuery, it is not working as expected.

My first jTable code is:

```
$('#SelectCode').jtable({
    selecting: true,
    paging: true,
    actions: {
    listAction:// my back end connection here
    },
    fields: {
        codes: {
            title: 'Code',
        },
        name:{
          title: 'Name',
        },
    },
    selectionChanged: function () {
    var $selectedRows = $('#SelectCode').jtable('selectedRows');
        if ($selectedRows.length > 0) {
            $selectedRows.each(function () {
                var record = $(this).data('record');
                Code = record.event_codes;
               $('#System').jtable('load',{code:(SelectedCode)});

            });
    },
});
```

My second jTable code is:

```
    $('#System').jtable({
        selecting: true,
        paging: true,
        actions: {
            listAction:// my back end connection here
        },
        fields: {
            date:{
                title:'Date',
            },
            Time:{
              title:'Time'
            },
    },
});
```

So, can someone, please help me how can I achieve in eliminating the empty rows from the table.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved it by adding the following line of codes in my jTable fields:

```
 display: function(data) {
                   if (data.record.date == null) {
                        $("#System tr").each(function() {
                        var cellText = $.trim($(this).text());
                        if (cellText.length == 0) {
                          $(this).hide();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    return data.record.date;
                },
```